# TLS v1.2 ciphers to use in PHP NUSOAP SoapClient

Tags: php, soap-client, nusoap, tls1.2

I want to connect to a server that only supports TLS 1.2. What possible ciphers can I specify to stream context in the PHP NUSOAP SoapClient creation?

```
<?php
    $objSoapClient = new SoapClient(
        "https://example.com/?wsdl",
        array(
            "encoding"=>"ISO-8859-1",
            "stream_context"=>stream_context_create(
                array(
                    "ssl"=>array("ciphers"=>"<????>")
                )
            )
        )
    );
?>
```

Comment: is the answer below OK?

Comment: Your answer below is OK for PHP SoapClient. I am also looking for a way to do the same using PHP NUSOAP API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TLS v1.2` is described in `RFC5246`, you can [read it here](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt). List of ciphers you can find [in openssl wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Ciphers(1)#TLS_v1.2_cipher_suites), use the second line without trailing `256`. You can manually get a list of ciphers used by running `openssl ciphers -v | grep -v 'TLSv1.2'` on the server in case you have access to it.

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    [
        'ssl' => [
            'ciphers' => 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA',
        ],
    ]
);
```

List of ciphers in TLS v1.2

```
 TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256                  NULL-SHA256

 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256           AES128-SHA256
 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256           AES256-SHA256
 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256           AES128-GCM-SHA256
 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384           AES256-GCM-SHA384

 TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256        DH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
 TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256        DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256
 TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256        DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
 TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384        DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

 TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256        DH-DSS-AES128-SHA256
 TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256        DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256
 TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256        DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
 TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384        DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384

 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256       DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256       DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256       DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
 TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384       DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

 TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256       DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256
 TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256       DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256
 TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256       DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256
 TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384       DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384

 TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256      ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256
 TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384      ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384
 TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256      ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
 TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384      ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

 TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256    ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
 TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384    ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
 TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256    ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
 TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384    ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256     ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384     ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256     ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384     ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256   ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384   ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256   ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384   ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

 TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256       ADH-AES128-SHA256
 TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256       ADH-AES256-SHA256
 TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256       ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256
 TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384       ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```